# How to pass input array and output array to procedure using spring data jpa and without creating connection object?

Tags: spring-boot, stored-procedures, plsql, spring-data-jpa

I have a stored procedure in Oracle which takes two arguments - one array as input and another array as output.

How to call the procedure using Spring Data JPA way and without creating Connection object, session, struct, and oracle array.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures), we can see the `String` element as an input argument and it's working fine. But when tried to give `List` and `array` as input arguments it's failing.

There are many similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them have a Spring Data JPA solution.

Looking for a solution like the below:

```java
    @Procedure("GET_TOTAL_CARS_BY_MODEL")
    Object[] getTotalCarsByModel(Student[] inpArray);
```

(or)

```java
    @Query(value = "CALL FIND_CARS_AFTER_YEAR(:inpArr,:outArry);", nativeQuery = true)
    Object[] findCarsAfterYear(@Param("inpArr") Student[] inpArr);
```

I tried with both of the above kinds of invocation, but it does not work. Can anyone please help me to achieve it **without using EntityManager or Connection Object reference** ?

Comment: Do you have entity and repository classes?

Comment: yes of course, as mentioned in the baeldung reference link

Comment: Do you have to use procedure? What you want to achieve seems to be doable with `Query Methods`. And why passing Student to Car repository?

Comment: I can't change my client requirement and hope you understand

Comment: Good question, too bad that there is no answer for it for years. There can be valid reason why to use stored prod in project with hibernate and you need to pass array of entities to it, but every answer there is for this question is always trying rephrase question and solve it differently (without any luck, actually). Even springdata jira it's like:: look! It's shown how it's done in our documentation [providing link which does not show it whatsoever].